# How to Decode the Azure JWT token in Rust to use the payload in my application

Tags: azure, rust, jwt

I have an API that is connected to PostgreSQL using sqlx crate and I have a web server deployed using Actix web.

I am requesting for a JWT token from: `"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}/v2.0/token"`.

this JWT will have some payload, I am trying to decode my jwt like so in rust:

```
use jsonwebtoken::{decode, decode_header, Algorithm, DecodingKey, TokenData, Validation};
use jwt::{Claims, VerifyWithKey};
fn main() {
    let jwt = "";
    let token_data = decode::<Claims>(&jwt, &DecodingKey::from_secret(b""), 
    &Validation::new(Algorithm::RS256));
    println!("{:?}", token_data);
}
```

but I get this error when I compile it in my terminal:

```
Err(Error(InvalidAlgorithm))
```

I verified the algorithm used from jwt.io: `'alg': 'RS256'` on the header part.

I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

I just want to decode the JWT and use some stuff from the payload to do further actions
any suggestions will be helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of hunting on the web:

I used a crate called `jsonwebtokens`
turns out it gives a very simple and neat way to decode and get the headers as well as the payload:

```
use jsonwebtokens as jwts;
use jwts::{Algorithm, AlgorithmID, Verifier, raw::{self, TokenSlices}};
#[derive(Serialize,Deserialize, Debug)]

pub struct Claims {
    pub aio: String,
    pub app_displayname: String,
    pub aud: String,
    pub roles: Vec<String>,
    pub tid: String,
}

let get_azure_jwt = get_bearer_token(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret, url_scope).await;

let TokenSlices{claims,..} = raw::split_token(&get_azure_jwt).expect("Error Slicing the token");
let raw_claim = raw::decode_json_token_slice(claims).expect("Error getting the claims");
let final_claim:Claims = serde_json::from_value(cls.clone()).unwrap();
```

then you can use the decoded claims as needed.